# Null Reading config file with getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, file

I have a class that reads a config file from the project root but it is not finding the file.

My read class is in com.br.xxx.util package

```
        String filename = "config.properties";
        input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

This code returns null even though
"config.properties" is in my project root. What am I doing wrong?

If I use:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\git\\projectfolder\\project\\config.properties");
configFile.load(input);
```

It works, but I don't want to use a system path.

Comment: `config.properties` must be in your `classpath`. how do you run your project?

Comment: i run with tomcat9

Comment: so put `config.properties` in WEB-INF

Comment: The getResourceAsStream() method needs a "class-path". But you are providing only a file name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi did not worked

Comment: System.getProperty("user.dir"); will return current working directory. With the help of current working directory you can get your file. Thanks

Comment: probably there is a `classes` in WEB-INF. move file to classes.

Comment: @VinitMehta it just returned the same file system path from windows that i wrote on the working code example.

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi worked after moving to /classes, you can write it as answer.

Comment: Yes because you said I don't want to use system path, so you need to create a folder in current directory and place that file then you will only be able to get that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config.properties must be in your `classpath`. when you deploy your project on tomcat, by default `WEB-IN/classes` is in `classpath`. Simplest solution is to move `config.properties` to `WEB-IN/classes`.

Comment: Nice, after this i created a folder conf and added it to my classpath.